# Overlaying of 2 images doesnt work properly

Tags: java, image, png, jpeg

I am trying to merge two images a PNG/TIFF file over a JPEG image. I am using the following code

```
try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test\\a.jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     BufferedImage overlay = null;
                    try {
                        overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test\\b.png"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                     // create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes
                     int w = Math.max(image.getWidth(), overlay.getWidth());
                     int h = Math.max(image.getHeight(), overlay.getHeight());
                     BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                     // paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
                     Graphics2D g = combined.createGraphics();
                     /**Set Antialias Rendering**/
                     g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                     /**
                      * Draw background image at location (0,0)
                      * You can change the (x,y) value as required
                      */
                     g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

                     /**
                      * Draw foreground image at location (0,0)
                      * Change (x,y) value as required.
                      */
                     g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);

                     g.dispose();

                     // Save as new image
                     try {
                        ImageIO.write(combined, "JPG", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test\\c.jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But, then final image that is forming is not according to what i want. Please refer to the attached images for clarity. [image: a] [image: b] [image: c]

Comment: The PNG image should have transparent background so you can see the image below it. Does it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use smaller images for the test. 3) Is the 3rd image the result of combining the first 2?

Comment: 1) this is the code which i have
2) This code works with two PNG files, but not with JPEG and PNG/TIFF
3) yes..it is..

Comment: Actually I am using a TIF image with transparent background, and as tiff image is very large, I can't post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Combine Images]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class CombineImages {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL urlImage1 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png");
        // Load the FG image (must have transparent parts)
        final Image fgImage = ImageIO.read(urlImage1);
        int w = fgImage.getWidth(null);
        int h = fgImage.getHeight(null);
        // Create a non-trasparent BG image
        final BufferedImage bgImage =
                new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // Create the final image
        final BufferedImage finalImage =
                new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = finalImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(fgImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,5,5));

                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bgImage)));
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(fgImage)));
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(finalImage)));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working perfect in case of this example, but dosnt seem to work when i replace BG image with a JPG file

Comment: Huh.. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17816277/418556) for follow-up.